# Partition usb stick / HDD with multiple ISO files

Tags: linux

Is it possible to partition a USB stick / HDD so i can choose between multiple boot images? For example i have boot images for

1. Debian 7.4.0
2. Ubuntu
3. Windows
4. Custom Linux boot images

And it would be easier to work with a USB stick / HDD with multiple boot images files i can choose from instead of having multiple USB sticks one for each boot image.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible. There is a piece of software called Ventoy that lets you do just that. You can get it here: https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html